# replace a pattern with some other text in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I want to replace a pattern with some other text in Notepad++

I have multiple lines which follows a similar pattern like below

row.createCell(2).setCellValue(adClickedVO.getKeywordCount());
row.createCell(3).setCellValue(adClickedVO.getModelName());

Where I want only to replace **row.createCell(2).setCellValue** with some other text(*values.add*) and not the entire line .

So my desired output will be some thing like this.

values.add(adClickedVO.getKeywordCount());

values.add(adClickedVO.getModelName());

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There are no tricks here. Just highlight the specific text and replace it with another text. Have you tried that?

Comment: but the number keeps on changing and I don't want to go and replace it manually for each and every line

Comment: my problem is that I have a common pattern row.createCell(?).setCellValue where any number replaces the ? .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

Find what: `row\.createCell\(\d+\)\.setCellValue`
Replace with: `values.add`

Where `\d+` stands for one or more digit.

Comment: @Toto, this yields Find: Cant' find the text `row\.createCell\(\d+\)\.setCellValue`?

Comment: @CroCo: Have you checked `Regular Expression`?

Answer (score 0):

Select that text and do Ctrl + F , go to second tab "Replace" and copy your text from which you want to replace and then click Replace all button.

Comment: Thanks @Mohit that I also know how to do that , but I my problem is that I have a common pattern  row.createCell(?).setCellValue where any number replaces the ? . Hope you got it this time.